# Shape property which references documentsheet property doesn't get updated when documentsheet property changes

Tags: visio

I have the following case:

I defined a user property ("User.DocProp") at the documentsheet level. I want to reference this property in a shape property cell ("Prop.SomeProp") and display the shape property as text on the shape.

This is working (I inserted a field into the shape text which points to my shape data). The value of the document property is correctly displayed on the shape.

And when I change the document property the shape's text gets updated. Awesome!

BUT this (update of the shape's text after change of the document property) doesn't work anymore when I have multiple pages each with the same kind of shape as before. When I now change the property on the documentsheet only those shapes get updated which lay on pages that I have navigated to before (since I opened the drawing). On all other pages the shape text will show the old value of the document property. Only when I directly enter the cell in the shapesheet by pressing F2 and leave with ENTER the text will get updated.

I tried several formulas in the shape property with no avail:

- =TheDoc!User.DocProp
- =SETATREF(TheDoc!User.DocProp)
- =SETATREF(TheDoc!User.DocProp,SETATREFEVAL(SETATREFEXPR()))

I can't find a method to force recalculation of formulas neither. What am I missing here?

[Screenshot from test drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAONZ.png)

Comment: May be [this article](https://visioport-ru.translate.goog/blog/index.php/34-thedocref?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp) can helps ?

Comment: Very interesting read indeed. But if I understand correctly I am using approach 1 which should yield in immediate update of the reference. And my problem is slightly different since in my case *some* references are updated (on pages I have navigated to before) and some are not (on the remaining pages). *This* is what confuses me.

Comment: Did you try **Print preview** for update fields?